# Is this phrase structure grammar from my textbook correct?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsing

I just started reading "Parsing Techniques, A Practical Guide", Second Edition, by Dick Grune and Ceriel J.H. Jacobs.

On page 12, the authors start describing a set of rules that can be used to generate the set of all enumerations of names of the type "tom, dick and harry": the rules allow single names (e.g. "tom") as well as repetitions ("tom, harry, dick, dick and harry"); multiple names in an enumeration are separated by commas except the last two names which are separated by "and", so the following aren't valid: ("tom, harry, dick") or ("harry and tom and dick").

A few pages later, and after having defined some more terms and formalisms, the authors come up with the following replacement rules (parse structure grammar) to generate the sentences of the desired type:

```
0. Name -> tom | dick | harry
1. Sentence-> Name | List End
2. List -> Name | Name, List
3. , Name End -> and Name
```

In the above, **Sentence** is the start symbol.

However it seems to me that these rules can generate incorrect sentences: if we replace **Sentence** by **List End** and **List** by **Name** we end up with **Name End** for which no replacement rule is defined.

It seems to me that the 2nd line in the rules above, if replaced by

```
Sentence -> Name | Name, List End
```

would fix this problem.

Am I correct that the authors have made an oversight, and is my modification correct? Or have I misunderstood something?

I don't have a CS background and this is the first time I'm reading about parsing, so please keep that in consideration in your replies. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, in a sense. Speaking in formal notation, you have

$\qquad \displaystyle \mathtt{Sentence} \Rightarrow \mathtt{List}\ \mathtt{End} \Rightarrow \mathtt{Name}\ \mathtt{End}$

and we can not get rid of $\mathtt{End}$. We have not generated a wrong *word*, but a sentence that can not be derived further to any word. That is not a mistake in the grammar itself (with respect to the generated language), but certainly nasty if you think of parsing.

Your modification is valid. In particular, we do not need to generate lists of length one using rule 2 (which you make impossible by your modification) because we can just alternative 1 of rule 1.

Note that the grammar given is not the greatest (for parsing). For example, it is not [context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free) (rule 3). A better way to implement detection of the end is to generate the list the other way round ($\_$ denotes a space):

$\qquad \displaystyle \begin{align}
  \mathsf{Sentence} &\to \mathsf{Name} \mid \mathsf{List}\ \mathtt{and}\ \mathsf{Name} \\
  \mathsf{List} &\to \mathsf{Name} \mid \mathsf{List}\ \mathtt{,\_}\ \mathsf{Name} \\ 
  \mathsf{Name} &\to \mathtt{tom} \mid \mathtt{dick} \mid \mathtt{harry}
\end{align}$

Of course, this grammar is now [left-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) which is problematic for some parsing strategies (e.g. [LL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parsing)). So it may be useful to create the list from left to right after all, but keep generating the $\mathtt{and}$ at the start:

$\qquad \displaystyle \begin{align}
  \mathsf{Sentence} &\to \mathsf{Name} \mid \mathsf{List}\ \mathtt{and}\ \mathsf{Name} \\
  \mathsf{List} &\to \mathsf{Name} \mid \mathsf{Name}\ \mathtt{,\_}\ \mathsf{List} \\ 
  \mathsf{Name} &\to \mathtt{tom} \mid \mathtt{dick} \mid \mathtt{harry}
\end{align}$

Now a parser working from left to right can always identify the next rule (with a lookahead of two to catch whether there is a comma behind a name).

Comment: Thanks. At this point the book hasn't gotten into some of the things you mentioned, so I'll reread your answer once I'm a bit further along.

Comment: @Aky: I thought it might not, and wrote the answer with that in mind. I would assume the authors to go on and change the grammar successively into something (easily) parseable. Have fun reading!

Comment: Actually, I now find that a bit further down the authors state: " A determined and foolhardy attempt to generate the incorrect form without the and will lead us to sentential forms like tom, dick, harry End
which are not sentences and to which no production rule applies. Such forms are called blind alleys." Hm.

Comment: @Aky Oh, right. Got me there. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Raphael: Without meaning to make too much of this, are grammars that lead to "blind alleys" relevant because some languages would be difficult to specify otherwise, i.e. it would be easier to "get rid of" occasional sentential forms that can't be derived further, than to have to specify a grammar that makes such cases impossible in the first place(?)

Comment: @Aky Yes, you can always (and algorithmically) get rid of dead/useless rules and symbols; grammars without such are called *reduced* grammars. The construction can be found in formal language textbooks, e.g. Harrison's "Introduction to formal language theory.", theorem 3.2.1.